# Horror movie where the hero is knowingly resurrected each day to kill and be killed

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Every new day the guy (our hero is some sort of zombie or vampire) gets up from the dead to kill and be killed knowing that he is going to be resurrected the next day to kill again. A reverse *Ground Hog* movie?

I think the movie is from the '80s or '90s.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: Was the protagonist white? Black? Asian? Greenskinned zombie? Was this in English? Did it appear to have been overdubbed?

Comment: And was he actually stuck in a loop? Or did he just keep getting resurrected?

Comment: Makes me think of https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Bomb

Answer (score 4):

The Deaths of Ian Stone

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0810823/

Ian Stone is murdered each day by horrifying pursuers, only to wake up in slightly different lives to experience the terror of being murdered again.

Answer (score 3):

Way out there in terms of timeline, but let's get the obvious one out of the way.

[Edge of Tomorrow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Tomorrow) a Tom Cruise movie from 2014 about defeating an alien invasion by having our hero loop through the same day over and over.

> The film takes place in a future where most of Europe is occupied by an alien race. Major William Cage (Cruise), a public relations officer with limited combat experience, is forced by his superiors to join a landing operation against the aliens, only to find himself experiencing a time loop as he tries to find a way to defeat the invaders.

The hero revives each time he dies.

> His attempts to warn Farell against the invasion are ignored and he experiences the loop of dying on the beach and waking at Heathrow repeatedly.